# IBM MQQueueManager not rollong back under TransactionScope C#

Tags: c#, transactionscope

My code on a higher level does the following:

1. Get the message from the SQL table.
2. Puts it on IBM queue.
3. Updates SQL table message is sent.

These steps are done in a C# TransactionScope.

When an exception is thrown (tried doing it explicitly) from code as one of the test cases, the TransactionScope rolls back SQL update but the message on IBM queue doesn't get rolled back.

**DTC enabled on the web server.**

```
#region Send Message                            
                        for (int n = 0; n < rowIds.Count; n++)
                        {
                            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted += Current_TransactionCompleted;
                                    using (var wmq = new WmqConnection())
                                    {

                                        byte[] msgId = wmq.WriteMsg(rowsData[n]);

                                        //writes to the text file
                                        writer.WriteLine("MessageID:" + BitConverter.ToString(msgId) + " ||RaInterfaceDataID:" + rowIds[n] + " ||Message:" + rowsData[n]);

                                        using (SqlConnection connection2 = ConnectionFactory.GetConnection())
                                        {
                                            #region Mark Interface Data Complete
                                            connection2.Open();
                                            sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Update InterfaceData Set Status = 'C' Where IntrfceDtaID = " + rowIds[n] + " and Status = 'F'", connection2);
                                            rowsEffected = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                            if (rowsEffected != 1)
                                                throw new TransactionAbortedException();
                                            #endregion
                                        }

                                        throw new TransactionAbortedException();

                                    }

                                    //scope.Complete();
                                }
                                catch (TransactionAbortedException tex)
                                {
                                    throw tex;
                                }

                            } //transaction scope ends

                            n++;
                        } //send message ends
```

//Code to send message (another method)

```
ConnectMQ();
                MQConnectOptions mco = new MQConnectOptions();
                queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
                queueMessage = new MQMessage();
                queueMessage.WriteString(inputMsg);
                queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
                queuePutMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
                queuePutMessageOptions.Options = MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT; 
                queue.Put(queueMessage, queuePutMessageOptions);
                return queueMessage.MessageId
```

Comment: `TransactionScope` is only partly magical. Code running in it is not automatically transacted, but only if it actually supports enlisting in an ambient `TransactionScope`. Apparently, `WmqConnection` does not support that. (Merely supporting transactions somehow is not enough, although such support can be used to build `TransactionScope` support.)

Comment: WmqConnection is my custom class which internally uses MQQueueManager.

Comment: That's fine, but then my comment applies with no modification to `MQQueueManager`. Is any support for `TransactionScope` documented?

Comment: They have some online example, one I found at: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029300_.htm